# When do we use minterm over maxterm in real words example or vice versa?

Tags: boolean-algebra, terminology

This may sound stupid. We have minterms. It is a **product** of all variables in a function and that function has the property that it is equal to 1 on exactly one row of the truth table.

What do we call if we have a product of all variables in a function and that function has the property that it is equal to 0 on exactly one row of the truth table?

On the other hand, We have maxterms. It is a **sum** of all variables in a function and that function has the property that it is equal to 0 on exactly one row of that truth table.
also, What if we call it if we have a sum of all variables in a function and that function has the property that it is equal to 1 on exactly one row of the truth table?

Comment: I'm a bit confused how your Boolean expression looks like if its both a product, but also only zero on a single line. I think you really might want to write down an example of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your questions to attract answers, do not start the text with a "This may sound stupid" statement. You show courage posting the question which you might fear to be downvoted or derided, but one has to have a comparable or greater courage to answer the question that declares itself "stupid".

You better try and prove that

> a product of all variables in a function [minterm] ... [which] has the
> property that it is equal to 0 on exactly one row of the truth table

is possible only when there is just one variable, i.e., the function is an identity or negation.

It is an exercise in Boolean calculus, and not bluntly trivial and unnecessary. For example, [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form#Functional_equivalence_2) posits

> It is apparent that maxterm n gives a false value (i.e., 0) for just
> one combination of the input variables. For example, maxterm 5, a′ + b + c′,
> is false only when a and c both are true and b is false—the input arrangement where a = 1, b = 0, c = 1 results in 0.

Notice, the article says 'it is *apparent*', and illustrates this statement with an example of a three-variable maxterm -- illustrates, but not proves. You can correct this omission, if only for individual use.